# CPU load of JSON export within Docker container

Tags: docker, nosql, couchbase

I have a Couchbase instance running as container. I'm thinking on exporting a bucket from there by `cbexport`.

The thing is that the bucket has 3M documents and it's size is approximately 2GBs and I'm not sure if it's going to be easy for CPU and RAM to export that data. Is it too much to work with for a system?

Comment: I suspect it will be fine. Is it just one node running in your local machine? Is there any risk to trying it?

Comment: Actually it's prod environment's master node and it makes me nervous

Comment: Have you thought about setting up XDCR to a different cluster, and then export from that second cluster?

Comment: I haven't thought about it before, thanks for the idea. That's what I'm going to do.